# Skip item when not found in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've this script that delete OneDrive item but I'm just wondering how can I modify my script so that when the item is not found then just skip for that item instead of stop executing.

Right now I'm getting this error and it stop executing.

```
Error: Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

Should I do try catch inside my forEach?. Will that prevent it from stop executing?.

The reason I'm asking it here first is because it deleting over 4million items and I'll never know when it will occur.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username/"
$ListName = "Documents"
$FolderServerRelativeURL = "/personal/sfdsf/Documents/PC-sdfd-sdf-01-Dec-0257"

Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -useWebLogin
    $List = Get-PnPList $ListName

        
    #Get All Items from Folder in Batch
    $global:counter = 0;
    $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 5000 -Fields ID, FileDirRef, FileRef -ScriptBlock `
    { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity `
            "Getting Items from Folder '$FolderServerRelativeURL'" -Status "Getting Items $global:Counter of $($List.ItemCount)"; }
 
    #Get List Items from the folder and Sort List Items based on Server Relative URL - Descending
    $ItemsFromFolder = $ListItems | Where { $_.FieldValues["FileDirRef"] -match $FolderServerRelativeURL } | Select-Object @{Name = "ServerRelativeURL"; Expression = { $_.FieldValues.FileRef } }, ID | Sort-Object -Descending -Property ServerRelativeURL
    Write-host "Total Number of Items Found in the Folder:"$ItemsFromFolder.count
          
    #Delete List Items in Batch
    $Batch = New-PnPBatch
    ForEach ($Item in $ItemsFromFolder) {
            Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Item.ID  -Batch $Batch
            Write-host "Item Queued for deletion:"$Item.ServerRelativeURL
            Invoke-PnPBatch -Batch $Batch -Details

    }
    Invoke-PnPBatch -Batch $Batch -Details
 
}
Catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Comment: Which command is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on Darin's answer. I checked the online documentation for the Remove-PNPListItem and it does not have a ErrorAction argument therefore you need to use the $ErrorActionPreference variable to actually get the Catch to work as it only works on terminating errors.

```
$ErrorActionPreference =  "Stop"

try {
    Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Item.ID  -Batch $Batch
} catch {
    #Write-Host "Missing $ListName"
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
```

That said I don't have that package installed so you might want to just try adding -ErrorAction "STOP" to your Remove-PnPListItem and see if it works before trying the Preference Variable.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks for this. so I'm supposed to put the $ErrorActionPreference inside my ForEach or outside? Also I'm curious how assigning "Conitnue" value will make it stop. I'm new to PS so I'm kinda confused what's going on.

Comment: Ziico, you can do it as shown above. The option is to just add the -ErrorAction "Stop" argument at the end of the Remove-PNPListItem command. That is actually the preferred action since it is better coding. However, as I said from the online documentation it doesn't show the command supporting that syntax which is why I used the option I did in the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry... I'm still getting the same errors and it stop executing agian.:(

Comment: I don't want the execution to stop even when I get that error tho.

Comment: Ziico, the Stop only forces the Catch clause to work it does not stop your code but rather it continues with the Catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the line number throwing the error and wrap the line in a try/catch.  Assuming the line turns out to be the Remove-PnPListItem command, then it would look like this (If you want to see what is missing, then uncomment the Write-Host and modify it as you desire.):

```
try {
    Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Item.ID  -Batch $Batch
} catch {
    #Write-Host "Missing $ListName"
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a page on "Everything you wanted to know about exceptions":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions

Comment: oh ok. so it deleting in batch right now so if the item is not found then it'll skip for that batch instead of stop executing right?.

Comment: ziico, "try" will try any code you put in it and if it throws an error such as you described "error and it stop executing", then "catch" will catch the error and run that code instead.  But in your case, you don't appear to want to do anything, other than maybe getting a report of what caused the error.  But you have to find the offending line and place it in the "try" part of the statement.  So find that line number to verify what line crashed, and wrap it in try part followed by catch.  The catch part is required, but it doesn't have to have anything in it.

Comment: Also, this doesn't apply to your situation, but might be good to keep in mind for the future.  I've ran into situations where an error message appeared, but execution didn't stop and try/catch didn't work.  A common parameter that can be used is ErrorAction.  Here is a good page to read about ErrorAction: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/

Comment: If you want a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's - bewilderingly complex - error handling, I recommend this (my) summary in [Our Error Handling, Ourselves - time to fully understand and properly document PowerShell's error handling](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).